# hidden file removal on ubuntu

Tags: delete, rm, hidden-files

I have PDF files in a hierarchical directory stucture to 4 levels on my webserver.
The files were uploaded from an OSX machine to a Windows Machine to my server.
I now have many (dot) .filenames.pdf that I wish to remove whilst keeping the actual filename.pdf file.
I would like to this with one line of shell script.
many thanks for your time. Simon

Comment: I will try a recursive rm -r ./._* on the top folder. That should to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) command. Example:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/.//' **
```

- the -n does not actually execute the command. So if you are satisfied remove the `-n` and run it again. Do make sure you have a backup.
- the `shopt` allows for using `**` and that makes it recursive (only with `bash`).
- this will run into an "arguments list too long" if it is lots of files. 
  You could do this from a script to go around that:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar
  for i in **; do 
      rename -n 's/.//' "$i"; 
  done
  ```

Comment: find . -name ._\* -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f

Comment: I read that as that you want to remove the . to make it unhide and not to remove the files.